# Service / component instantiation in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm implementing a simple forum, and I want my `ReplyService` to notify other services when a new `Reply` is saved. For that I defined an interface:

```
public interface PostEvent<T> {
    void onPost(T obj);
}
```

And allowed subscribers to my `ReplyService`:

```
@Service
public class ReplyService {

    private List<PostEvent<Reply>> postEvents = new ArrayList<>();

    (...)
    public void subscribe(PostEvent<Reply> obj) {
        postEvents.add(obj);
    }
}
```

In my `NotificationService`, I've just wrote a @PostConstruct method to subscribe to my `ReplyService`:

```
@Service
public class NotificationService implements PostEvent<Reply> {

    @Autowired
    private ReplyService replyService;

    @PostConstruct
    private void initialize() {
        replyService.subscribe(this);
    }
    ...
```

And it worked perfectly: when a new `Reply` is saved, my `NotificationService` runs its event implementation.

My doubt is: I didn't autowired my `NotificationService` anywhere in the project, but it is still running. Why?

Comment: All spring beans are by default singletons and eagerly initialised

Comment: If you are using spring boot, there is an implicit package scan to register all beans in same package or sub packages of @SpringBootApplication

Comment: Because `@Service` itself is annotated with `@Component` and as @Cyril G. mentioned, implicit package scan got the service `bean` created at Spring container